# vba excel check for cellnames

Tags: vba, excel, cell

i´vg got a little problem with my VBA-Script.
I want to search in a specific worksheet if a cell name exists.

```
Sub Zellenname_suchen()

Dim Tabelle As String 
Dim STG(0 To 100, 0 To 2) As String 'Array
Dim iSTG, jSTG As Integer

'read Array
  For iSTG = 3 To 100                       
    For jSTG = 0 To 1                       
        STG(iSTG, jSTG) = Sheets("Tabelle").Cells(iSTG + 1, jSTG + 1).Value
    Next jSTG

    If Range(STG(iSTG, 1) & "_SWnummer").Value = STG(iSTG, 1) & "_SWnummer" Then
        '
        ' Code
        '
    End If
  Next iSTG

End Sub
```

But this code won´t work. The fault is in line 13.

```
Runtimeerror'1004':
Die Methode 'Range' für das Objekt '_Global' ist fehlgeschlagen
```

Also the explicated definition of the worksheet dosn´t work

```
If Sheets("Tabelle").Range(STG(iSTG, 1) & "_SWnummer").Value = STG(iSTG, 1) & "_SWnummer" Then

Runtimeerror '1004':
Anwendungs- oder objektdefinierter Fehler
```

thx for help
Feder

Comment: Error on this line? `If Range(STG(iSTG, 1)...`  THat is because you can't use your *Array* as a means of indexing a Range object.

Comment: Hello David, the range by using the array-variable should be not the problem. i get also the fault when iam using with static Names like: `If Sheets(Tabelle).Range("SWnummer").Value = "SWnummer" Then ...`

Comment: You say you're checking for cell "names", but there is no such property of a cell.  Consider adding some more information, or clarifying exactly what you are trying to do.  That line might also fail if the named range is not present on the `ActiveSheet` at run-time (you did not qualify the range to a worksheet).

Comment: Why don't you just create a collection/array/dictionary of *existing* names, and then query against that list? Seems more reliable than whatever you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

Error 1004 indeed means that the specified (named) range is not found. Try to debug this, by stepping trough the options.

First, make sure the error comes from that line, so isolate the error make a new sub with only this:

```
Sub jzz()

Debug.Print Range("test_1").Value 'substitute 'test' with whatever name you have

End Sub
```

If this runs ok, and prints the value of the range, start to construct the string. So instead of the "test_1" I used, I would do something like:

```
Sub jzz()
Dim i As Long

i = 1
Debug.Print Range("test_" & i).Value

End Sub
```

If this doesn't run properly, you could print the string you constructed before entering it into the range, by using:

```
Debug.Print "test_" & i
```

Check if that is what you expect of it.

And continue from there. Debugging is breaking things down and repair each individual part. Then build your complete solution once again, one brick at a time. Test and test and test again. If you learn how to debug, you learn to code (better).

I'm sure you will find something that triggers the error, and even it out. Please come back if you run into trouble.